# Setting S3 object expiration (for deletion) with the JavaScript API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the Node.js JavaScript API for Amazon AWS S3, and would like to set objects to expire a specified number of days after the objects are created.  That is, if I create and upload a new object, I want it to automatically delete itself 100 days or so from now.  Is this possible to set expiration for deletion on a per-object basis?

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectExpiration.html) indicates this may be possible:

> Amazon S3 provides an Expiration action that you can specify in your lifecycle configuration to expire objects.
>
> …
>
> When an object reaches the end of its lifetime, Amazon S3 queues it for removal and removes it asynchronously. There may be a lag between the expiration date and the date at which Amazon S3 removes an object. You are not charged for storage time associated with an object that has expired.

However, it seems that I would have to set this expiration in the bucket configuration, and not per-object when I upload/create them.

The [JavaScript SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html#!http%3A//docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) indicates that I can set an `Expires` parameter when creating an object, but this seems to be for the `Expires` HTTP header when S3 returns the object for subsequent GET requests.

Is there a way to set the expiration date of an object when creating it?

```
s3.putObject({
  Bucket: config.s3.bucketName, 
  Key: s3Key, 
  Body: objBuffer,
  ACL: 'public-read',
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  StorageClass: 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
  // Some option here for setting expiration/deletion date?
}, function () {
  console.log(arguments);
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can not set expiration rules on each object individually. To define object expiration rules, you have to define a bucket [lifecycle configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html).

To do this with the node.js API, see the [putBucketLifecycle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketLifecycle-property) call. You can also check out the REST API docs for the [bucket lifecycle PUT operation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTlifecycle.html).

Comment: I wonder why all aws sdks mention "Expires" parameter if it's impossible to use it. Any explanations?

Comment: The "Expires" parameter that you're describing refers to the `Expires` HTTP header that you can define on an object. That header has no effect on the S3 object's lifecycle, it only affects how long clients (browsers, proxies, etc.) keep that object in cache once it's retrieved from S3.

Comment: does lifecycle rules deletes all objects after certain time or from the time of their creation, what I mean is, if I have a bucket and am uploading objects after some interval, will all the objects in bucket be automatically deleted after 24 hrs or from the time of their creation?

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3